# Double-Tap in TalkBack in Android 11

Tags: android, talkback

I'm in the process of integrating TalkBack into Android 11 on a custom platform. While most functionalities are working smoothly, I've encountered an issue with the double-tap feature.
Currently, TalkBack interprets a single tap with two fingers as a double-tap, but strangely, it ignores a double-tap with a single finger.

Any insights on what might be causing this issue? How to properly implement the double-tap functionality?